# Redirection to Another Vue or Page using Vue Form Wizard

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to VUE JS and currently trying to understand how we can redirect to another vue or page after the form is submitted. I am currently using the following sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-form-wizard-demo?file=src%2FApp.vue.

Am able to configure the form correctly and need some directions/example of how we can redirect to another vue or page after receiving response.

```
<template>
    <h1>Vue 3 Form Wizard Demo</h1>
    <vue-form-wizard :form="wizardQuestions" v-model="formData" @submit="handleForm(formData)" />
</template>

<script>
    import VueFormWizard from 'https://unpkg.com/@anivive/vue3-form-wizard@1.0.1/dist/index.umd.js';
  import './index.css';
  import wizardQuestions from './wizardQuestions.json';

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueFormWizard
  },
  methods: {
    handleForm(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      formData: [],
      wizardQuestions: wizardQuestions
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
    #app {
        font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        text-align: center;
        color: #2c3e50;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
</style>
```

I did try this.router.push and getting undefined error.

Comment: "I did try this.router.push" - where? "getting undefined error" - which error exactly? There's no this.router, it's this.$router

Comment: Flask, Tried the same. That didnt work too. I tried it in the handleForm function.

Comment: Likely means that you don't have a router properly configured. In order to use $router, you need to set up router plugin

Comment: I am new to Vue JS. Just wanted to know is that the only ONE way to redirect to another page/Vue?  @EstusFlask

Comment: This is the proper way to do this in Vue, because otherwise you'll have to implement route navigation yourself. You can redirect with window.location.href, but unless you've implemented routing already, this will still show main page

Answer (score 0):

The official recommended routing solution according to the Vue documentation is to use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/). I see it is not currently part of your code sandbox, so that is why your attempt at using `router.push()` failed. It does not come with Vue by default, so you'll need to install it separately.

Alternatively, if you have very simple routing needs you may be able to get away with just using dynamic components as also noted in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html#simple-routing-from-scratch)

This is the example code from the docs for your reference:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import Home from './Home.vue'
import About from './About.vue'
import NotFound from './NotFound.vue'

const routes = {
  '/': Home,
  '/about': About
}

const currentPath = ref(window.location.hash)

window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
  currentPath.value = window.location.hash
})

const currentView = computed(() => {
  return routes[currentPath.value.slice(1) || '/'] || NotFound
})
</script>

<template>
  <a href="#/">Home</a> |
  <a href="#/about">About</a> |
  <a href="#/non-existent-path">Broken Link</a>
  <component :is="currentView" />
</template>
```